# CodeIgniter not loading CSS and JS while migrating website from one domain to another domain and hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter

While migrating the website. I'm not able to load CSS and JS files in my Codeigniter project.

**FOLDER STRUCTURE:**

```
home > username > public_html > application > [ cache , config , controller, core, ... ]
home > username > public_html > media > admin > [ attachment, css, datepicl, ...]
home > username > public_html > media > front > asset > [css, fonts, img, ...]
home > username > public_html > media > uploads > [associatepartner, banner, ..] 
home > username > public_html > system > [core, database, ..]
```

`config.php` < config < application < public_html

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/domain.com';
```

`header.php` < layout < front < views < application < public_html

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo FRONT_MEDIA_URL; ?>asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo FRONT_MEDIA_URL; ?>asset/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo FRONT_MEDIA_URL; ?>asset/css/reset.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo FRONT_MEDIA_URL; ?>asset/css/style.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo FRONT_MEDIA_URL; ?>asset/css/responsive.css">
```

Help. Thanks! (Do let me know if I need to furnish more details)

**EDIT: view-source:http : / / domain.com/** (Please ignore spaces in between http.)

```
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http : / / localhost/domain/media/front/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http : / / localhost/domain/media/front/asset/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http : / / localhost/domain/media/front/asset/css/reset.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http : / / localhost/domain/media/front/asset/css/style.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http : / / localhost/domain/media/front/asset/css/responsive.css">
```

**EDIT: Added `constants.php`**

`constants.php` < config < application < public_html

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
if (sSITE_MODE == 'live') {
    define('URL', 'https://www.theother2thirds.net/');
} else if (sSITE_MODE == 'beta') {
    define('URL', 'https://www.theother2thirds.net/');
} else {
    define('URL', 'http://localhost/theother2thirds/');
}
```

Comment: Well what you really need to do straight away is go to your page in your Browser, and view source to view the generated HTML and inspect your CSS Links... What do you see?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, Thanks for your response. Please check I've added generated HTML snippet.

Comment: Apart from the issue where you have "spaces in the wrong places". What you try next is to take one of those urls, i.e http://localhost/domain/media/front/asset/css/style.css (with the spaces removed) and put that in your browser. Do you get to see the style.css code?

Comment: http://localhost/theother2thirds/media/front/asset/css/style.css while trying this URL. I'm not getting any style code. It is giving me **Error 404**

Comment: Your last edit regardng your constants.php changes the goal posts. That wasn't in your original question, everythings changed... How come sSITE_MODE and URL  is now involved???

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, I am migrating a website from one domain to another as well another hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base_url is defined as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/domain.com';
```

You will need to load the url helper in your controller or you can autoload it, then you can utilise the function `base_url()`.

Then you have a choice of either using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url('asset/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>">
```

OR you can assign FRONT_MEDIA_URL

```
defined('FRONT_MEDIA_URL') || define('FRONT_MEDIA_URL', base_url());
```

BUT you will need to have loaded the url helper prior and you've not shown where you have declared that, but that is for you to figure out.

**UPDATE due to new information**
See if you can use this
Now I do not know where you are defining sSITE_MODE but this is an option to help with the use of base_url() in your site...

In **application/config/config.php** you could do something like

```
defined('sSITE_MODE ') || define('sSITE_MODE', 'live');

if (sSITE_MODE == 'live') {
    $migration_url = 'https://www.theother2thirds.net/';
} else if (sSITE_MODE == 'beta') {
    $migration_url = 'https://www.theother2thirds.net/';
} else {
    $migration_url = 'http://localhost/theother2thirds/';
}

$config['base_url'] = $migration_url;
```

OR just define the correct Constant and use it. You have **FRONT_MEDIA_URL** in your links and then you are talking about using **URL**. You need to use the correct one.